# Encrypting Emails with Outlook (Office 365 E3 or something else)

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, encryption, office365

We have Office 365 Enterprise E3. I activated and set up the `Azure Information Protection`. The software is currently on a couple of machines.

What I noticed is that decryption requires the end user be specified in the label's policy and that the recipient have `Azure Information Protection`.

Is there a way that the recipients specified in the "To" and/or "CC" fields can open the message without my having to create a customized policy? I was thinking of a simple policy/label, where recipients can open and respond, while others cannot.

Is there another option for Office (Outlook) 365? I am new to Office 365 email encryption and definitely with Azure Rights.

**Question Summary:**

What steps are required to get a client up and running, so that they can read emails?

1. Install `Azure Information Protection`
2. ?

Comment: Please read the following article about configuring email encryption in Office 365. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/securitycompliance/define-mail-flow-rules-to-encrypt-email if you have further questions please be more specific about what steps you have already taken. Encrypted email does not require anything be installed on a machine nor that a recipient have anything special on their end. For triggering encryption you can use DLP policies and/or detecting certain keywords in the subject or certain destination domains, etc. in your transport rule.

Comment: @Appleoddity The referenced doc is no different than adding in a label in the Microsoft `Azure Portal`. I have to know IN ADVANCE the person, who will receive the email. The purpose of my question was to have a button in Outlook that says `Encrypt` and ANYONE receiving that email gets an encrypted message. My thought is something simple that a 3-year old can send and receive an encrypted email to anyone with no PhD in Microsoft complicated necessary.

Comment: yes, I understand your intention. I see Microsoft has changed to a newer system with slightly different features and I think you are diving in headfirst in to that. I can tell you we have been using Office 365 email encryption using a transport rule for years now. No extra software needed, nothing needed on the recipient’s end. It’s simply not an issue. The user puts the word `encrypt` in the subject line and it’s done.  Think about it, if it were all as you say, it wouldn’t be very useful would it? I’ll take a look at this other new feature.

Comment: @Appleoddity I am not married to Azure, heck I hate the name. I got the task to add encryption to Outlook. We already have E3, so I implemented it. I just sent a test email to my manager, & he got "you have to authenticate yourself" or something, which brought up a dialog. That did not go far. He wants to send encrypted emails to some of our customers. No one in their right mind will jump through these many hoops. Maybe a 3-year old would be okay and just 50ish year old people have issues.

Comment: @Appleoddity You did not say which software you use, how to test that, implement that, or the end user experience. For instance, Raytheon has a much simpler email system from what I understand, so I know that it is possible.

Comment: Im sorry for your troubles but it seems this post is more of a rant than a sincere request for help. Half our workforce is over 50 and nobody has trouble using Office 365 email encryption. It takes 5 minutes to implement and has worked very well for us. So, if and when you are ready to detail exactly what steps you have taken and your results I’m not able to help. At its very simplest stage it takes two simple transport rules and that is what I have been trying to tell you and is documented so I’m not sure where you’re going wrong.

Comment: In addition, if you have E3 then you have support from Microsoft. You could be talking to a professional and have the system setup to your desire within the day.

Comment: @Appleoddity Okay, I changed the question/summary.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94505/discussion-between-appleoddity-and-sarah-weinberger).